# html table not formatted correctly

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to format this HTML so it looks like this:
http://iforce.co.nz/i/tryvopws.4xy.png

I can't seem to get it right though! I can make the top part work but then the other sides resize to be really small. I want it to look like the picture.

Any help is appreciated!

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
      <tr class="s4-die">
       <td class="ms-pagebreadcrumb">
       </td>
        <td valign="top" width="100%">
               <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="WebPartZone1" Title="loc:Top" />
               &#160;
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
         <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;">
          <tr>
           <td valign="top" width="60%">
               <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Left" Title="loc:Left" />
               &#160;
           </td>
           <td>&#160;</td>
           <td valign="top" width="40%">
               <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Right" Title="loc:Right" />
               &#160;
           </td>
           <td>&#160;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td valign="top" width="60%">
               <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Left2" Title="loc:Left" />
               &#160;
           </td>
           <td>&#160;</td>
           <td valign="top" width="40%">
               <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Right2" Title="loc:Right" />
               &#160;
           </td>
           <td>&#160;</td>
          </tr>
         </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have and extra column remove that

```
 <td class="ms-pagebreadcrumb">
 </td>
```

or turn it into a row

```
 <tr class="s4-die">
   <td class="ms-pagebreadcrumb">
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="s4-die">
     <td valign="top" width="100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

The first row you need to add `colspan="2"` so that it spans the full length as shown in your example.

Also you wouldn't need to add another table in that table. That is causing your one td to be larger than the other and may look very messy. using the `colspan` , `cellspacing` , and `cellpadding` you should be able to accomplish what you need.